# How to define new router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For this question I am referring to the **vuestic-admin** template from https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin

This template is the most suitable template for me. However, I want to make some changes. To be exactly, I want to add a new page, but dont want this page shown in the sidebar. To do this I need to define new router. My problem is: I dont quite understand how to add new router.

Hier is what I have done:

**Firstly**, I made a `.vue` file in `components/contact/Contact.vue`. Its code:

```
<template>
  <div class="contact">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>contact</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default { name: 'contact' }
</script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

**Secondly**, I added a new .js file in `store/modules/contact.js`. Its code:

```
import lazyLoading from './lazyLoading'

export default {
  name: 'Contact',
  path: '/contact',
  component: lazyLoading('contact/Contact'),

  meta: {
    default: false,
    title: 'menu.contact',
    iconClass: 'vuestic-icon vuestic-icon-extras'
  }
}
```

**Thirdly**, in the `store/modules/menu/index.js` file, I changed the `state` defination by adding `pages`:

```
import contact from './contact'

const state = {
  pages: [
    contact
  ],

  items: [
    dashboard,
    statistics,
    forms,
    tables,
    ui,
    extra,
    auth
  ]
}
```

**Fourthly**, in `router/index.js` file, I made following changes:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    ...generateRoutesFromMenu(menuModule.state.items),
    {path: '*', redirect: { name: getDefaultRoute(menuModule.state.items).name }},
    ...generateRoutesFromMenu(menuModule.state.pages),
    {path: '*', redirect: { name: getDefaultRoute(menuModule.state.pages).name }}
  ]
})
```

By compiling the changes above I get the console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Based on my knowledge (and my guess) the problem should be in the fourth step.

Could anybody please show me a way out of this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say you don't want the route to appear in the menu but you are taking all the steps for it to appear. Have you read the router [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html)? It is as simple as a using a string key to point to a component

Comment: @sklingler93 Thanks for the reply. For generally adding router I might know how to do. I actually dont know how to add router into this template. Besides, in step three I made pages to contain the pages I dont want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source [here](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin/blob/2cd6c60309320bc9e84fdf718342f0529250c1f7/src/router/index.js) for `getDefaultRoute()`,

```js
function getDefaultRoute (menu = []) {
  let defaultRoute

  menu.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.meta.default) {
      defaultRoute = item
    } else if (item.children) {
      let defaultChild = item.children.find((i) => i.meta.default)
      defaultRoute = defaultChild || defaultRoute
    }
  })

  return defaultRoute
}
```

I would say that you don't need the line

```js
{path: '*', redirect: { name: getDefaultRoute(menuModule.state.pages).name }}
```

since for contact you have set `default: false` and there are no children, which means the function returns null (hence the error message you received).

The framework seems to assume a single list of menu items and one of them to be set as default. But I think your approach should work.

<s>The only potential problem is that it looks like you are changing framework code, which means a bit more work when upgrading to next version of the framework.</s>

---

### A note about upgrading

I just ran the basic install, and looking at the project I have to revise my remark about a potential upgrade problem.

Essentially, this is a template not a framework. The difference is that the installer creates starter code in your project's src folder, which you can freely modify and save to a github repository.

There is no package under node_modules that would overwrite your router changes when you run `npm install` on your project at a future date.

If epicmaxco create a new version of the template that you wish to use, you would simply create a new project and copy the changes you previously made within src to the new project (perhaps run a diff of the old and new src folders).

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually this template has much features that I like at first sight. At the very beginning I have not realised such kinds of problems like "single list of menu items" or "upgrade". It is now becoming really a big annoying but also a challenging task for me.

Comment: Should I ask you if you have any recommendations for template to avoid the "single list of menu items" or "upgrade" problems?

Comment: I must wait to get 15 reputations to give you the repu-score. :-)

Comment: Actually, this is the first time I've seen the template but I also like it. I will have a look at the best way to customize without upgrade problems and post if I find anything.

Comment: That will be great. Thank you in advance!